# How to display text in my wordpress post except if it's in a certain category?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display certain text in all my posts except if it's in this one category. How do I do that? Oh yea I almost forgot I want to include the title of the post in the text. So I think I need to use echo, cat='-5', and  or something?? I don't know how to form it though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Wordpress function [in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category). When you use it inside the loop, it returns true if the current post is a member of the category you passed it.

```
<?php 
if ( in_category('my-category'))
{
    // don't output text
} else {
    // do output text
}
?>
```

Comment: In addition, to output text, you use `echo`. The display the title, use the ubiquitously named `the_title()` function, eg `echo the_title(), ' is in my-category';`

Comment: `the_title` outputs the title, it does not return it, so you can't echo it. If you wanted to use echo for some reason, `echo get_the_title()`.

Comment: @Dan Yes, I know but you can also use `echo` like that. Figured it would look nicer and make more sense to the OP than `the_title(); echo ' is in my-category';`

Comment: You said to write `echo the_title()`, which makes no sense, as `the_title` does not return anything for `echo` to print...  if you wanted to concatenate a string, actually do it: `echo get_the_title() . ' is in my category';`

Answer (score 0):

Do you require the text to be completely locked away, or just hidden from view? If you only need it hidden from view (but accessible to anyone who chooses to pry) then you may be able to do it very quickly using css.

If you have coded your theme - or are using someone else's - that adds helpful styles into the header, you may have a lot to work with already. For example, this is a body declaration generated by the Thematic theme:

```
<body class="wordpress y2011 m01 d31 h12 archive category category-orthopaedics">
```

Say you have a chunk of content to hide:

```
<div class="text_to_hide">This is what gets hidden.</div>
```

Then you declare the CSS as:

```
.category-orthopaedics .text_to_hide { display: none; }
```